# synchronize cygwin installed packages between multiple machines

Tags: git, sync, cygwin

I have 4 machines that I'm trying to keep in sync ie. same settings and installed packages. Is there a folder that I can add to a repo and use git to keep in sync so that i can guarantee consistency accross the board(I'm more interested in installed packages but settings would also be nice to keep in sync.)?

Comment: " Is there a folder that I can add to a repo" -- can you clarify what the question is?  Is your question just whether you can use git to sync the machines?

Comment: My question is indeed can I use git to sync the machines and which folders would I want to sync?

Comment: There is a solution to duplicate the installed packages here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829532/cygwin-save-package-selections-for-later-reinstall/ it can be also applied for multiple machines